# Windows 11 with multiple monitors that aren't vertically aligned - how to *prevent* mouse from going between monitors if not on seam

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-11

My current monitor layout is like this:

[image]

When I move my mouse from the top half of 3 to the left, instead of hitting a "wall" as it has done in previous Windows versions (I believe that was previous behavior), it now jumps to the top of 1. This makes it difficult to hit buttons on the top left of 3 because if I overshoot, it will go to the top of 1 but when I move back I'll be in the middle of 3 (... move up and left, overshoot again, repeat).

Is there a way to disable this behavior so that it instead hits the wall and stops?

Comment: Is that image from the displays control panel, or did you just draw it yourself?

Comment: @Tetsujin it is a cropped screenshot of my setup.

Comment: @Danijel that did it, thank you! Ease cursor movement was the magical setting. If you make it an answer I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouse, right click on your Desktop,

Pick "Display Settings" and on new screen locate 4th option for;

"Ease cursor movement between displays".

[image: How to find "Ease cursor movement between displays"]

Comment: Hi Danijel, this is obviously the correct answer for the OP, but it doesnt really help other future visitors.  You could add a screenshot of the settings

Comment: The behavior is proportional to resolution of both screens, it takes a bit of time to get use to it(i have weird setting on work with 4 screens, but they make sense while looking at them) but its generally faster with that option enabled.